# Determining if a trivial extension $\mathbb Z(+) \mathbb Z_{2^\infty}$ is Bezout

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be the ring $\mathbb Z(+) \mathbb Z_{2^\infty}$ where $ \mathbb Z_{2^\infty}$ denotes the [Prüfer 2-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) and $A (+) B$ denotes the trivial extension, which is the ring given by coordinatewise addition on $A\times B$ but multiplication given by $(a,b)(a',b')=(aa',ab'+ba')$.

I have convinced myself it is arithmetical and now I'm trying to determine if it is moreover Bezout.

---

Bezout means its finitely generated ideals are principal.  Of course, it suffices to prove it for 2-generated ideals.  However, I was not able to decide this either way.  I got nowhere finding a formula for a generator of $((n,a),(m,b))$ in terms of the unknowns, and the things I thought might make likely counterexamples actually seemed to work out (I tried pairs like $(2,0)$ and $(0, a)$ where $a$ is of order $2$, and $(2,a)$ and $(0, 2a)$ where $a$ is of order $4$.)

Anyone have any insight on how to crack this sort of thing?

Comment: I think the fact that the Prufer group is infinitely generated stops it from being Bezout. Unless I'm mistaken, elements of the form $(0,b)$ are an infinitely generated ideal.

Comment: @ZoeAllen Bezout rings can and do have infinitely generated ideals… it’s not an impediment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplication by an integer $a$ is surjective $\Bbb{Z}_{2^\infty}\to \Bbb{Z}_{2^\infty}$ whenever $a\ne 0$.

And $( 1, b) \in R^\times$

So $(a,b) R  = a (1,b')R = (a,0)R$ whenever $a\ne 0$

$(0,b)\in (a,0)R$ whenever $a\ne 0$.

So $(a,b)R+(c,d)R = (\gcd(a,c),0)R$ whenever $a\ne 0$ or $c\ne 0$.

The remaining case is $(0,(2A+1)/2^B)R+(0,(2C+1)/2^D)R = (0,1/2^{\max(B,D)})R$

Comment: What is $1/2^k$ supposed to mean in $\mathbb Z_{2^\infty}$?  Well... either way, the "remaining case" is trivial since the subgroups of $\mathbb Z_{2^\infty}$ are linearly ordered.

Comment: The first line of this solution is what I was missing!  It's so strange for this group to be both torsion and divisible...  That makes it look like the ideals are easy to understand: every ideal not contained in $0\times\mathbb Z_{2^\infty}$ is something like $(n)\times \mathbb Z_{2^\infty}$ and the rest are linearly ordered inside $0\times \mathbb Z_{2^\infty}$.

Comment: Agree that this ring is strange

Comment: the reason I was looking at this ring is as an example of a "torch ring" and it looks like it is. I half suspected it wasn't because I don't believe any of the literature on torch rings uses this ring, despite it seeming like a natural candidate.  Torch rings do seem to be pretty scarce, since they are kind of "edge cases"

Comment: Perhaps unclear that with $A/2^B,A\ne 0,B\in \Bbb{Z}$ I meant $A/2^B+\Bbb{Z}\in \Bbb{Z}[2^{-1}]/\Bbb{Z}=\Bbb{Z}_{2^\infty}$, eg. $\exp(2i\pi A/2^B)$.